# Create an exe on publish in a .NET core project in VS2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, publish

I created a console application in .NET Core 2 and wanted to make it an executable file (so I don't have to launch it via Visual Studio 2017). The problem is that publishing the file into a local folder does not do that, there are DLL files, but no EXE.

[I know how to do it when creating a .NET Core Console application by command line](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/09/dotnet-core-console-app-create-exe-instead-of-dll/). I created a separate simple project and used

```
dotnet build -r win10-x64
```

My problem is that I want to publish my application from Visual Studio 2017. I'm trying to achieve that but with no results. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Command Line**

- `dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64`
- Replace `win10-x64` with any other [supported platform identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)

**VS2017**

- On the specific publish profile, click configure (next to target location). You must create the profile first - the UI is not intuitive on this.
- Select a *Target Runtime* from the list.
- To add more options to the list, add `<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` to some `<PropertyGroup />` in the `.csproj` file with a list of extra identifiers.